# CRUD operation while working with many to many relationships in EF-Core 2

Tags: c#, many-to-many, ef-core-2.1

I am currently reading a blog where there's an example of many-to-many relationships about books and author in asp.net core.

```
public class Book               
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }   
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<BookAuthor> AuthorLink { get; set; }
}

public class Author               
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<BookAuthor> { get; set; }
}

public class BookAuthor               
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }   
    public int AuthorId { get; set; } 

    public Book Book { get; set; }    
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

and the insert method is written as this:

```
var book = new Book
{
  Title = "Quantum Networking",
  Description = "faster-than-light data communications",
  PublishedOn = new DateTime(2057, 1, 1),
  Price = 220
};
var author = new Author { Name = "Future Person" };
book.AuthorsLink = new List<BookAuthor>
{
  new BookAuthor {  // WHAT IF THERE ARE MULTIPLE AUTHORS?
    Author = author, 
    Book = book,
    Order = 0
  }
};
```

How can i insert multiple comma seperated authors? Am I supposed to use a "foreach" loop inside the book.AuthorLink

Comment: No no, you have to change the model. It doesn't support multiple authors, as it stands now. (Edit the class, perhaps support an array or list of authors)

Comment: @Attersson Sorry! I just added the full model so not to confuse you.

Comment: I added the full answer, please note it was not a matter of "confusion" but part of the solution itself :) I also corrected line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have extended your model (that was part of the solution!), you can initialize the list with a list initializer:

```
book.AuthorsLink = new List<BookAuthor>
{
  new BookAuthor {
    Author = author, 
    Book = book,
    Order = 0
  },
  new BookAuthor {
    Author = author2, 
    Book = book,
    Order = 0
  },
  new BookAuthor {
    Author = author3, 
    Book = book,
    Order = 0
  }
};
```

Or just initialize the empty list and then a series of `book.AuthorsLink.Add(someAuthor)`

Comment: Check the fields in class Book though, they differ compared to your code snippet. For example PublishedOn doesn't exist, as well as Order.